# Entity Framework 6- Saving data in a transaction

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I need some help in understanding a situation we are trying to resolve in entity framework.

We are trying to update two tables 
1. Mapping table( two foreign keys = ProductId and anotherId)
2. Create a new record in a Table (call in Product and the generated primary keys is productId)

We want to ensure that both the product table and mapping table are successfully updated or else the transactions roles back.

We used a single transaction as

```
using (var context = new SomeContext()) 
{ 
    using (var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
    { 
        try 
        { //Create the record to be saved
            var product = new Product{ // set the data}
            var newProductId = context.SaveChanges(); 

            //Update the Mapping Table
            var anotherData = context.AnotherTable.where(x => x.id = anotherId).FirstOrDefault();
            var productData = context.Product.where(x => x.id = newProductId).FirstOrDefault();

          //Create the Mapping Table record  
          productData.AnotherDatas.Add(anotherData);
          context.SavceChanges();

          dbContextTransaction.Commit(); 
        } 
        catch (Exception) 
        { 
            dbContextTransaction.Rollback(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

But the Issue is that

```
var productData = context.Product.where(x => x.id = newProductId).FirstOrDefault();
```

comes back as null which i am assuming is due to the fact that the transaction is not committed.

How to overcome this scenario? 
How can i create the mapping record and use the newly created Id?
Does running multiple saves in the same transaction will lead to errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `product` to context to save it:

```
context.Product.Add(product);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Also `SaveChanges()` returns count of changed records, so look on `product.id` to retrieve the inserted record id after saving it.

Comment: thanks buddy...I was adding the product to the context but i think my head was all swamped and i was expecting the save to return the Id and did not realize it. There was another problem with my data that my table only had foreign keys and entity framework was treating it like a view and was not letting me update it... which make sense..i anyways needed to add primary key to my mapping which actually fixed it.

Comment: @fireholster, no problem! EF may work incorrectly if data have no unique identifier, even if a view is called. This link may be helpful: http://girlfromoutofthisworld.com/entity-framework-and-setting-primary-keys-on-views/